# Windows phone 8, Check if wifi is on?

Tags: windows-phone-8, wifi

I'm trying to make a joke app for windows phone. The app gets jokes from the internet so, I want it to be able to check if wifi signal or is able to connect to the internet. How will I go about creating that?

Comment: ping an ip that should/is always available like google's public dns? having wifi means nothing. that's like saying "I have a cup. why isn't it filled with beer?"

Answer (score 2):

In WP8.1 runtime you can query most of this stuff from `NetworkInformation` class like so:

```C#
// need this namespace
using Windows.Networking.Connectivity;

bool is_wifi_connected = false;
ConnectionProfile current_connection_for_internet = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
if (current_connection_for_internet.IsWlanConnectionProfile)
{           
    if (current_connection_for_internet.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
    {
        is_wifi_connected = true;
    }           
}
```

---

WP8.0 You can query most of this stuff from the `NetworkInterfaceList` like so:

```C#
// see is wifi is ON and connected
using Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation;

bool is_wifi_connected = false;
if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
{
    NetworkInterfaceList nif = new NetworkInterfaceList();
    foreach(NetworkInterfaceInfo item in nif)
    {
        if (item.InterfaceSubtype == NetworkInterfaceSubType.WiFi && item.InterfaceState == ConnectState.Connected)
        {
            is_wifi_connected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Now to see if it can connect to the website just open a connection.  You can use any web connection you like.  Just going to do this with a WebClient and an event handler when the file is done downloading.

```C#
using System.Net;

// check network and is_wifi_connected
if (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() && is_wifi_connected)
{
    WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute);
    downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadDone);
    downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
}

void DownloadDone(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error downloading the site.");
    }
    else
    {
        // your html file or what not is stored here
        string content = e.Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It says "NetworkInterfaceList could not be found"..., how can i make this work on windows 8.1?

Comment: @Hunt3R Your question is tagged Windows Phone 8.0, I gave you the solution to that.  You're saying you need it for windows 8.1?  Don't you mean Windows Phone 8.1?  And even if you said I need it for Windows Phone 8.1, it still not clear.  Re tagged your question or explicitly state that you are using Windows Phone 8.1 (runtime) or Windows Phone 8.1 (Silverlight) -- they are different things.

Comment: For windows phone 8.1 I get an error sayung that " NetworkInterfaceList could not be found". Thats the problem and another question is how can i do the same thing in windows 8.1?

Comment: @Hunt3R Like I said, saying Windows Phone 8.1 is still not clear.  Are you using Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight or Windows Phone 8.1 runtime?

Comment: Im not really sure :D but I created a universal app.. I copied you code and pasted in my Mainpage.xaml.cs page(windows phone 8.1). I think someone told me that it used WindowsRT api but im not really sure.. I'm a newbie so.. yeah.. cant really figure it out

Comment: @Hunt3R if you made a universal app, it is WP8.1 runtime.  I updated the solution to get whether WiFi is the active connection.  For getting a website, you will need to use something that WP8.1 runtime supports ... like a  `HttpWebRequest`, all of this information can be found on MSDN.  SO is not an alternative to reading.  You'll understand it better if you read the docs.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware, WebClient doesn't exist for windows 8

Comment: @demas If you read the comments, you will understand that you have to draw a line somewhere.  It's tagged for WP8, I wrote it for that.  Now he's asking for WP8.1 and windows, which is not tag for.  I will let one slide, but if this goes on, he probably ask for it to work for Windows 10 as well...